# Running Azure Powershell Inline Script

Tags: azure, powershell, tfs, azure-devops, devops

I have a powershell script in order to make a backup of a SQL Database. I run the script locally, i run the script on TFS release phase with **Powershell Script** (not the azure powershell task), and everything went well.

Now, i want it to run it with the `Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript` because i want to remove the login part from my powershell. I saved the username \ password in the variables in order to login and i want to get rid of that

This is the script :

[image]

Please notice that i put the `Login-AzureRmAccount` because of the error. After this, i'm still getting it.

Error message:

### [error]Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.

### [error]Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.

Comment: Your connection type should be Azure RM, not Azure Classic.

Comment: What should I change in order to use the classic one?

Comment: If I remove the login rm account part , I'm getting the same 2 errors

Comment: You can't change it. You're using Azure RM commands. You should use an Azure RM connection. Azure Classic won't work.

Comment: Where it has "Azure Connection Type," change the dropdown to "Azure Resource Manager" and you may need to create/update the service connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above please change the dropdown to "Azure Resource Manager" because in Azure classic this command will translate to Start-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy which does not have all the options available

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/start-azuresqldatabasecopy?view=azuresmps-4.0.0